# How to change the "value" and "id" of a button based on the selection of a separate set of radio buttons

Tags: jquery, forms, button, radio-button

I have a form that includes two radio buttons and a button. I would like to change the value of the button based on which of the two radio buttons is selected. My guess is that it's better to use jQuery than PHP for this, but please let me know if that's the wrong assumption.

Here's an example of the HTML:

```
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
     <input type="radio" name="basic" value="basic1">
     <label for="basic1">Basic 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="basic" value="basic2">
    <label for="basic2">Basic 2</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="basic1" name="startReg" type="submit" value="basic1">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

In short, I want to replace the button id and value with the value of whichever radio button is selected. So, if the second radio button is selected, the button tag will look like this:

```
<button id="basic2" name="startReg" type="submit" value="basic2">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: Why? The radio button value will be submitted, so why copy to the button?

Comment: may i ask why not use the value of the radio button on submit ?

Comment: I am doing it this way because the radio buttons and button will be used on a subsequent page, with those buttons preselected. The HTML above represents one of three columns. When the user selects the radio button for Basic 1, and then clicks on Confirm, I want the Basic 1 radio button and the Confirm button to be preselected on the following page. The user will then fill out additional information on the subsequent form. I gather from the two comments above that I'm doing this the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the names of the controls, and it will send the same form data as it would if you change the value of the button:

```
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
     <input type="radio" name="startReg" value="basic1" checked="checked">
     <label for="basic1">Basic 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="startReg" value="basic2">
    <label for="basic2">Basic 2</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="basic1" name="somethingElse" type="submit">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
$(':radio').on('change', function() {

  // this.value for get the id of radio

  $('button[name=startReg]')
                        .attr('id', this.value )   // change id of button
                        .val( this.value );        // update value of button
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/590/)**

but selected `radio` value will auto submit.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
  $('button').prop({'id' : $(this).val(), 'value' : $(this).val()});   
});
```